# React refresh component on login

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components, NavBar which contains a login modal and the 'body' of page.
I want to detect when a user logs in and re-render the page based on that. How do I update the login prop in the second component when I log in using the modal of the first one?

A simplified version of the code to keep it short:

// NavBar.js

```
export default class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.initialState = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      loginModal: false
    }
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this)
 }
 handleLogin(e) { 
  e.preventDefault()
  loginAPI.then(result)
 }

 render() {
 return( <nav> nav bar with links and login button </nav>)
}
```

// Some random page

```
export default class Checkout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      order_type: 'none',
      loggedIn: false
    }
    this.Auth = new AuthService()
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.Auth.loggedIn()) {
      const { username, email } = this.Auth.getProfile()
      this.setState({ loggedIn: true, email: email })
    }
    try {
      const { order_type } = this.props.location.state[0]
      if (order_type) {
        this.setState({ order_type: order_type })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('No package selected')
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log("this.props, prevState)
    if (this.props.loggedIn !== prevProps.loggedIn) {
      console.log('foo bar')
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section id='checkout'>

          User is {this.state.loggedIn ? 'Looged in' : 'logged out'}

      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

// App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes /> // This contains routes.js
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

// routes.js

```
const Routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route exact path="/registersuccess" component={RegisterSuccess} />
    <Route exact path="/faq" component={FAQ} />
    <Route exact path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
    <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    {/* <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> */}
    <Route path="/(notfound|[\s\S]*)/" component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the react context API to store information about the logged in user.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

#### Example

auth-context.js

```
import React from 'react'

const AuthContext = React.createContext(null);

export default AuthContext
```

index.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import AuthContext from './auth-context.js'

const AppWrapper = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, setLoggedIn }}>
      <App />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppWrapper/>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
)
```

Then inside any component you can import the `AuthContext` and use the `Consumer` component to check if the user is logged in order set the logged in state.

NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import AuthContext from './auth-context.js'

const NavBar = () => (
  <AuthContext.Consumer>
    {({ loggedIn, setLoggedIn }) => (
      <>
        <h1>{loggedIn ? 'Welcome' : 'Log in'}</h1>

        {!loggedIn && (
          <button onClick={() => setLoggedIn(true)}>Login</button>
        )}
      </>
    )}
  </AuthContext.Consumer>
)

export default NavBar
```

#### HOC version

with-auth-props.js

```
import React from 'react'
import AuthContext from './auth-context'

const withAuthProps = (Component) => {
  return (props) => (
    <AuthContext.Consumer>
      {({ loggedIn, setLoggedIn }) => (
        <Component
          loggedIn={loggedIn}
          setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn}
          {...props}
        />
      )}
    </AuthContext.Consumer>
  )
}

export default withAuthProps
```

TestComponent.js

```
import React from 'react'
import withAuthProps from './with-auth-props'

const TestComponent = ({ loggedIn, setLoggedIn }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{loggedIn ? 'Welcome' : 'Log in'}</h1>

    {!loggedIn && (
      <button onClick={() => setLoggedIn(true)}>Login</button>
    )}
  </div>
)

export default withAuthProps(TestComponent)
```

Alternatively if you have redux setup with `react-redux` then it will use the context API behind the scenes. So you can use the `connect` HOC to wrap map the logged in state to any component props.

Comment: Would having something like this be a bad idea, didnt want to wrap my whole code: <nav> <AuthContext.Consumer> {this.state.isLoggedIn ? setLoggedIn(true) : setLoggedIn(false)}  </AuthContext.Consumer> .. rest of the nav bar </nav> or is there a way I can update the AuthContext from my handleLogin(e) ?

Comment: You can create a HOC function to make adding the props easier without importing the context. I added an example.

Comment: @Trax you can use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook instead of the `Consumer`

Comment: @TameemSafi very nice solution. How do you make sure that the AuthContext updates when the login status of the user changes? I have a similar setup, where I query the data based on a session cookie in the Provider, but it updates only on forced reload.

Comment: @FabianBosler when you change the value of the provider it will automatically update all of the consumers. You can either pass a function inside of the value object to change the the logged in state or change it within the place you pass the value object into the provider (ex `AppWrapper` component) . Using the example above, I am passing the `setLoggedIn` method which the consumer uses to update the `loggedIn` part of the state which is passed into the provider value object.